# Assign value of existing column to new columns in pandas based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to create a new column in pandas data frame based on existing columns.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | y1 | y2 | y3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |

I want a new columns **vals** which take values of **col1 if currentyear = y1 and col2 if currentyear = y2**

| column1 | column2 | column3 | y1 | y2 | y3 | Vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 200 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 100 |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 300 |

I am trying below code :

```
    def assignvalues(df):
        if df['y1'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col1']
        elif df['y2'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col2']
        elif df['y3'] == currentyear:
            df['Vals'] = df['col3']
```

```
df.apply(assignvalues)
```

It does create columns but doesn't store any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
... column1,column2,column3,y1,y2,y3
... 100,200,300,2020,2021,2022
... 100,200,300,2021,2022,2023
... 100,200,300,2019,2020,2021"""))
>>> df
    column1 column2 column3 y1      y2      y3
0   100     200     300     2020    2021    2022
1   100     200     300     2021    2022    2023
2   100     200     300     2019    2020    2021
```

And the function `assignvalues`, which now return the value from the expected column for each `if`. We set the `currentyear` at `2021` for example :

```py
>>> def assignvalues(df):
...     if df['y1'] == currentyear:
...         return df['column1']
...     elif df['y2'] == currentyear:
...         return df['column2']
...     elif df['y3'] == currentyear:
...         return df['column3']

>>> currentyear = 2021
```

We can assign to `df["Vals"]` an `apply()`, as you did, with an `axis=1` parameter to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df["Vals"] = df.apply(assignvalues, axis=1)
>>> df
    column1 column2 column3 y1      y2      y3      Vals
0   100     200     300     2020    2021    2022    200
1   100     200     300     2021    2022    2023    100
2   100     200     300     2019    2020    2021    300
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helped me reached the solution with one more additional line where i convert y1 in df as string and take current year as string as well. 

Initially without typecasting to string it was still returning empty rows.

ex: `df['y2']=df.y2.astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for faster execution, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

currentyear = pd.to_datetime('now').year

condlist = [df['y1'] == currentyear, 
            df['y2'] == currentyear, 
            df['y3'] == currentyear]

choicelist = [df['column1'],
              df['column2'],
              df['column3']]            

df['Vals'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

The default value if no match of currentyear is `NaN`, you can set it to 0 or other values at your choice by modifying the `default=` parameter.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   column1  column2  column3    y1    y2    y3  Vals
0      100      200      300  2020  2021  2022   200
1      100      200      300  2021  2022  2023   100
2      100      200      300  2019  2020  2021   300
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before as well and got the same issue, please let me know what i am doing worng. I am getting below error msg :

`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Do let me know if using this is faster than the if else conditional statement. Thanks

Comment: @user1855463  `.apply()` function is Python loop under the hood.  It is not optimized like numpy or other Pandas vectorized operations which has been optimized with C or CPython codes to make it run faster.

Comment: @user1855463  For your error, how your actual data is different from the sample data ?

Comment: Structure of the original is same as the sample, just col1/2/3 has float values (but can be converted to int if required)

Comment: @user1855463  Have you passed the `default=` parameter as I did ?   Also, are you specifying all 3 conditions instead of 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying with the default parameter
`import numpy as np
currentyear = pd.to_datetime('now').year
condlist = [dfloadbcaext7['y_1'] == currentyear, 
            dfloadbcaext7['y1post'] == currentyear, 
            dfloadbcaext7['y2'] == currentyear]
choicelist = [dfloadbcaext7['y_1grossprofiteur'],
              dfloadbcaext7['y1postgrossprofiteur'],
              dfloadbcaext7['y2grossprofiteur']]            
df['GPEUR'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)`

Comment: @user1855463  The codes looks ok.  It's difficult to trace the problem without seeing your actual data.  Anyway, if you already got what you want with another solution, just go ahead with that.  You can find out later if any problem.  If your dataset grows large and the execution goes slow, you can then revisit this faster solution.